What's making my app crash when I try to launch?
The app crashes before the homepage appears.
It returns a null pointer exception when trying to invoke android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()
I was attempting to animate a floating
action button so it expands and shows two other buttons.
I made xml animation files and attempted to add logic so the animations started when I tapped the fab but upon running the app, it crashes. I'm fairly new to Android development and a bit more experienced in java but don't know how to find or correct the null pointer exception.


private Animation rotateOpen() {
        return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_add_btn_open_anim);

    }

private Animation rotateClose() {
        return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_add_btn_close_anim);

    }

private Animation fromBottom() {
        return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_bottom_anim);

    }

 private Animation toBottom() {
        return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_bottom_anim);

    }


    Button addBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

    Button addTextBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_text_btn);

    Button addImageBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_image_btn);

    private boolean clicked = false;


onCreate(..) {

    ...

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> onFabExpanded());



        addTextBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.add_text_note,                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());



        addImageBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.add_image_note,                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

}



private void onFabExpanded() {



        setVisibility(clicked);

        setAnimation(clicked);



        clicked = !clicked;

    }



    private void setVisibility(Boolean clicked) {

        if (!clicked) {

            addTextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            addImageBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        else {

            addTextBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            addImageBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    }



    private void setAnimation(Boolean clicked) {

        if (!clicked) {

            addTextBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom());

            addImageBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom());

            addBtn.startAnimation(rotateOpen());

        }

        else {

            addTextBtn.startAnimation(toBottom());

            addImageBtn.startAnimation(toBottom());

            addBtn.startAnimation(rotateClose());

        }

    }


Do not call findViewById() on a field initializer. Call it after you call setContentView().

Did you look at the logs?

@DavidConrad I did, that's how I found the null pointer exception

@CommonsWare I called findViewById after the setContentView in the onCreate method and then the log showed another error saying that I was attempting to cast a floating action button to a button. And after changing the Button to FloatingActionButton it works as intended and the animations work as I expected. Thank you sooo much!
